# Using value of input field to filter results

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have been teaching myself web dev (using nodejs, mongodb) for a few days now and have run into a problem.

I have two tables which I need to join, followed by summing certain columns, and finally filtering (using a user specified threshold) based on the value of these sums. I do all this using *aggregate* pipeline.

The join and creation of columns works fine.
To filter, first I create a new column, *isAResult*, and use *match* to retain the records that return true for that column.
This is how I create *isAResult*.

```
 { $project: {   isAResult: {$cond: { if: {$gte: ["$totalkcal", val_kcals]}, then: true, else: false }}
```

where val_kcals is initiated earlier as shown below.

```
var val_kcals = req.body.val_kcals;
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: is `totalkcal` a field from joined collection ?

Comment: @Veeram Yes it is. In a previous step I join the two tables and sum their columns to get `totalkcal`.

Comment: Can you add the complete query please and some sample doc along with expected json output ?

Comment: @Veeram Thanks. I managed to solve the problem. It was a casting issue, ```val_kcals``` as declared above is not a number. I will post an answer when I get back home.